# Different range slide distances

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I am using jQuery UI Slider (from min to max) and need to achive this result:

```
|----------------------.---------|
0                     300       500
```

From 0 to 300 I have step value of 1, and slide width 70%, and from 300 to 500 (70% to 100%) step is 25. I know how to change step dynamicly, the problem is different width (distances). How to make 0-300 cover 70% of slider and 300-500 only from 70% to 100%? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On slide action check handle position from left. Haven't checked it, but the idea might work

```
$( "#your-slider" ).on( "slide", function( event, ui ) {

    var handler_pos = $( '.ui-slider-handle' ).position().left;
    var slider_width = $( '#your-slider' ).width();
    var count = handler_pos/slider_width*100;

    if ( count > 70 ) {
        $( '#your-slider' ).slider( {'option', 'step', 25} );
    } else {
        $( '#your-slider' ).slider( {'option', 'step', 1} );
    }

});
```